# WinError 10038 Alternatives to sys.stdin on Windows?

Tags: python, sockets

I was reading up on [Python Networking](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_tcp_server_client_chat_server_chat_client_select.php) using sockets and found the code below at the end. I have the server file which works fine and starts the server on port 9009.

```
# chat_client.py

import sys, socket, select

def chat_client():
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
        print ('Usage : python chat_client.py hostname port')
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print ('Unable to connect')
        sys.exit()

    print ('Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages')
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in read_sockets:            
            if sock == s:
                # incoming message from remote server, s
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print('\nDisconnected from chat server')
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()     

            else :
                # user entered a message
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

   sys.exit(chat_client())
```

However, when I try the client part above, I get:

```
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

The lines where the errors are coming from are:

```
read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])
```

and

```
sys.exit(chat_client())
```

I've read other questions regarding the same error and their answers were that the sockets were closed before reading all the data. But in the above, there is no `socket.close()` function but there is in the server file. I have tried removing it, changing the indentation but still get the same error.

Also, reading on similar questions I have found out that `sys.stdin` is not a socket so that could be why I'm getting this error. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP?

Comment: It was one of the recommended tags.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, reading on similar questions I have found out that
>   `sys.stdin` is not a socket so that could be why I'm
>   getting this error. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

You could manage with periodical checking of input activity, e. g. by replacing your `select` statement with

```
        # Get the list sockets which are readable, time-out after 1 s
        ready_to_read = select.select([s], [], [], 1)[0]
        import msvcrt
        if msvcrt.kbhit(): ready_to_read.append(sys.stdin)
```

Note that in this example approach, when one began typing in a line, incoming messages will only be displayed after the input line is finished.

Answer (score 0):

i am having the same problem but not when it comes to close the socket, try s.close()

```
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

you set `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` = to `s` it is easier to use `s.close()` and should work, if you find the solution to the other problem let me know it is driving me crazy

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a comment rather than an answer. Wait to win some more reputation. Some OP will downvote your "answer"