# How to prevent fgets running multiple times when overflowing a buffer?

Tags: c

I have a problem where if a user enters an input greater than the max number of characters such as "abcdefg" when the max is 5, the `fgets()` that is within a loop runs twice and instead of "abcd" it instead prints out "abcd" then "efg".

I think this is because `fgets()` only processes up to the 4 characters and a null terminator but there is still "efg" that exists in the stdin buffer.

I was wondering if there was a way to only grab the "abcd" and discard the rest of any remaining input that is more than the max size of the allocated buffer.

```
#define INPUT_MAX 5
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char input[INPUT_MAX];
    while(1){
        printf("prompt> ");
        fgets(input, INPUT_MAX, stdin);
        printf("\n%s\n", input);
    }
}
```

Example RUN:

```
prompt> abcdefg   <-- I press enter once here for /n

abcd
prompt> 
efg

prompt> .         <-- I end up here after enter command
```

I found that `fflush(stdin)` is not a proper way to flush a stdin.

Comment: `for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';);` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear stdin before getting new input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715002/how-to-clear-stdin-before-getting-new-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing automatic. Check whether the input ends with newline. If it doesn't, call `getchar()` in a loop until you get newline or EOF.

```
while(1){
    printf("prompt> ");
    if (fgets(input, INPUT_MAX, stdin) == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    printf("\n%s\n", input);
    if (input[strlen(input)-1] != '\n') {
        for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';)
            ;
}
```