# Explanation about detecting end of line in C

Tags: c, scanf, newline

I'm reading/practicing with this book about C language: "C Programming - A Modern Approach 2" and I stumbled upon this piece of code whose explanation is odd to me:

> *Since* **scanf** *doesn't normally skip white spaces, it's easy to detect the end of an input line: check to see if the character just
>   read is the* **new-line** *character. For example, the following loop
>   will read and ignore all remaining characters in the current input
>   line:*

```c
do {
    scanf("%c", &ch);
} while (ch != '\n');
```

> *When* **scanf** *is called the next time, it will read the first character on the next input line.*

I understand the functioning of the code (it exits the loop when it detects *enter* or `'\n'`) but not the lesson(?).

What is the purpose of this, since to store the input from the user into `&ch` you HAVE to press the *enter* key (quitting the loop)?

Also what does "the following loop will read and ignore all remaining characters in the current input line" mean actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...What is the purpose of this*...

For context in understanding what this code snippet can be used for, take a look at *[this link](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)* discussing stdio buffering.
In simplest logical terms, this technique consumes content placed in *[stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)* until the `newline` character is seen. (From a user hitting the `<enter>` key.)  This is evidently the lesson.
This effectively clears the `stdin` buffer of content, also described *[in this more robust example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36723075/645128)*.

*Also what does*

> "the following loop will read and ignore all remaining characters in
>   the current input line"

*mean actually?*

```
do {
    scanf("%c", &ch);
} while (ch != '\n');
```

It means that if the new `char` just read by `scanf` is not equal to the newline character, defined as `\n`, it will continue to overwrite `c` with the next read.  Once `ch` does equal `\n`, the loop will exit.

Comment: My impression from the wording of the question is the OP does not know about buffering of input.

Comment: @Richard - Good point.  I've added a few lines, and links to touch on that.  Thanks

Comment: As @RichardChambers pointed out i'm pretty new to programming and I only know the basics (if I do) of _C_ . So the first part is out of my hands for now. Nonetheless thanks to the second part of your explanation I got the point that I was missing.