# C program prints to terminal instead of file even after using dup2/dup

Tags: c, linux, dup2, dup

I'm in an operating systems course and doing assignments with C on Linux.
In one of the assignments I was supposed to redirect and output to a file, but for some reason, I keep getting the output in the terminal instead.
I tried writing a simple program to do just that and it still didn't work:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int file1 = open("./text_try", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666) //open file
    printf("write to screen\n"); //print to screen
    int oldOut = dup(1); //save screen FD
    dup2(file1,1); //change output stream from screen to file
    printf("write to file"); //print to file
    dup2(oldOut,1); //change output stream from file back screen 
    printf("write to screen");  //print to screen
}
```

other things I tried :

1. changing the permissions on the file open (adding `O_RDWR`)
2. running on 2 separate PCs - i run mainly on remote desktop to the uni pc for linux but also got VMware on the laptop.
3. tried using `close` + `dup` combo instead on `dup2`
4. tried using conditions with `perror` to see if any step will tip me off as to why it doesn't work.
5. tried using `STDOUT_FILENO` instead of 1 for output

would really appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Start with adding error checking. `open()`, `dup2()`, etc. can fail and you need to handle it when they do.

Comment: Also read up on `open()` and what should be included in the second argument if you want to be able to write to that file.

Comment: For starters, remove the `O_EXCL` flag. That open call will fail if `text_try` already exists from a previous run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdio normally buffers output to `stdout` -- it's line-buffered when it's connected to a terminal, fully-buffered when connected to a file. Since you're not writing any newlines, it will not flush the buffer automatically in either mode. The buffer is flushed automatically when the program exits, at which time it gets written to the last stream that FD 1 is connected to.

Either turn off buffering with `setvbuf()`, or flush the output explicitly between `printf()` calls.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int file1 = open("./text_try", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666) //open file
    printf("write to screen\n"); //print to screen
    int oldOut = dup(1); //save screen FD
    dup2(file1,1); //change output stream from screen to file
    printf("write to file"); //print to file
    fflush(stdout);
    dup2(oldOut,1); //change output stream from file back screen 
    printf("write to screen");  //print to screen
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKED ! can you please explain a little more plainly why it works this way ? or maybe refer me to an article about it? THANK YOU SO MUCH !

Comment: Does this work the same for input but with fflush(stdin)?

Comment: `fflush()` causes undefined behavior on input streams. There are some implementations that extend it to input streams, but it's not standard. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: just tried using fflush(stdin) and it worked also ! did it right after scanf since i assumed that scanf is "the opposite" of printf

Comment: As I said, it depends on the implementation.

Comment: So don't use it in code that should be portable.

Comment: unfortunately it's supposed to be portable... know any other implementation that would work instead ?

Comment: [how to clear input buffer in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c) [how to clear stdin before getting new input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715002/how-to-clear-stdin-before-getting-new-input)